# Passing on jQuery HTTP Get (Django)

Tags: jquery, django

I've been debugging this for quite a while but can't find a solution. What I want is that when someone clicks a button, they send in a unique key generated by my view and certain IDs.

After doing so, I want to refresh 2 pictures on the page and update the autogenerated key with a new one.

When, I encounter a post, I process the data and return with

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

When I encounter a GET, I process the data, generate a key and provide 2 new images. I return with

```
return render(request,..
```

This is how I intend to update the unique_id using a template

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $.post("/", { 
      unique_id : "{{ unique_id }}",
      id1 : {{ id1 }},
      id2 : {{ id2 }},
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    });
  });
```

However, what I notice occuring is that I press the button to send in the POST and I receive a GET response with no errors. However, the GET response does not update the page and hence the unique ID is not updated, so when I press the button again to send in the next POST, I receive the old unique ID.

Is this because my HTTP GET is not being passed in from jQuery to the actual browser. Is there a step I missed? Since I do have a HTTP GET, is there anyway to get jquery to only update two tags and the unique ID?

Comment: What is the purpose of using ajax then if you want your page to be refreshed when a user clicks on something? Remember in ajax everything has to be manually updated. Write a `success` function of `.post` and update the images and unique ID's accordingly

Comment: I used AJAX because I wanted to embed unique IDs into the POST to verify that they are legitimately accessing the view through the template that I presented them. Should I have not used AJAX? Is there another approach? Once I verify the unique ID, I want to be able to update certain portions of the page. "Remember in ajax everything has to be manually updated. " Does that mean that when I am returning an HttpResponseRedirect in response to the POST, this is sent as text to my calling jQuery function and that I need to parse it to determine what components need to be updated?

Comment: Exactly you have to parse the response received from the ajax request and on success function check if everything is ok make your changes else alert the user an error. Also use `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({}), mimetype='application/javascript')` in your view.

Comment: I think you're not on the right path in the sense that you have your templates render your javascript with the relevant values. Concerning the get, I suspect the reason your server registers a get instead of a post is because you didn't prevent the default action of clicking a button. Try $('#button1').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $.post(...) )

Comment: Also I think there is no need of ajax here because you are trying to validate the `{{unique_id}}`, `{{id1}}`, `{{id2}}` which already comes from request context so before you render the template validate in your view if they are valid or not else raise `Http404` exception

Comment: Definitely, thanks for the help. I'm trying to validate incoming POST requests against unique_ids that match specific model fields. So, i'm not worried about rendering invalid unique_ids in the template but that the user might manually construct a POST request with values that I did not specifically give them in the template. So, I only validate on POST requests.